# bonding between wifi and eth

Tags: debian, network-interface, bonding

I would like to bond an eth interface with a wifi one, as a failover when I need to go free of cable (particularly at home). (This is on Debian testing)

But then, trouble is, how to set the wifi credentials ? Because I use the laptop in some other places. So I cannot place wifi-keys in the conf' file. It is not static conf'.

Is there a way I bond the two interfaces, but be able to manage the wifi conf' part aside ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: *Bonding* means that both `eth` and `wlan` interfaces are used as it was one single interface, to increase bandwidth. That especially means that there must be something on the other end of both the LAN and WLAN that can splice the split data together again. *Failover* (use WLAN when LAN is unplugged, otherwise use LAN) is quite a different thing.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding -> says bonding can be used to do failover.

Anyway, I want to do failover. Do you have some doc related to my case ?

Comment: In the case you have a fixed connection (always same WLAN, never move your laptop) AND a device on the other end that supports bonding via 802.3ad you can also configure it for failover (only use one of the interface at any time). But I still very much doubt that this is your use case. You are not a network center where hardware can fail, you want your laptop to use WLAN if it can't get LAN. Different thing.

Comment: Thing is that, I think my use case is pretty common, but I don't see it described often in blogs or other.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine and is a textbook example from the Debian wiki.

Debian allows the creation of a bonded interface that communicates with the DHCP server on its own terms and acts *virtually* independently of the other connecting interfaces.

> From the outside (=network) view it doesn't matter which interface is active. The bonding device presents its own software-defined (i.e. virtual) MAC address, different from the hardware defined MACs of eth0 or wlan0.
>
> The dhcp server will use this MAC to assign an ip address to the bond0 device. So the computer has one unique ip address under which it can be identified. Without bonding each interface would have its own ip address.

It looks like all the instructions you need are included on the page you linked to: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding

The WiFi config is specified by this configuration directive: `wpa-conf /etc/network/wpa.conf`

That is, it specifies `wpa.conf` as the file where the WPA configuration is stored.